# Issues with linking android with postgresql using jdbc driver

Tags: android, postgresql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

What i have done is tried two different ways. First one being writing all the code in the main activity class. But i read somewhere that you need to put it in a different thread or something and it suggested to use asynctask and that's the second way i tried.

Here's my code:

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    /*String sql;
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    new DatabaseConnectivity().execute(sql);*/

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        String url;
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nikhildb";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"postgres","5438");
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String relname = rs.getString("name");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,relname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Log.e("Worked", relname);
        }

        //rs.close();
        //st.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        //Log.e("Error","Error");
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Intent intent;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_piano) {
        intent = new Intent(this,PianoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_guitar) {
        intent = new Intent(this,GuitarActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_synth) {
        FragmentSynth fs = new FragmentSynth();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relView, fs).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {
        FragmentCart fc = new FragmentCart();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fc).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {
        FragmentOrders fo = new FragmentOrders();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fo).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        FragmentHome fh = new FragmentHome();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fh).commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
}

/*class DatabaseConnectivity extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ResultSet> {
public void onPreExecute(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ResultSet doInBackground(String... sql){
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try{
        String url;
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nikhildb";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"postgres","5438");

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql[0]);

        //rs.close();
        //st.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        Log.e("Error","Error");
        //Toast.makeText(this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs;
}

public void onPostExecute(ResultSet rs){
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            String relname = rs.getString("name");
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,relname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Worked",relname);
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        Log.e("Error","Showed error here");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

here's the error:

```
beginning of crash
07-05 23:00:25.159 3493-3493/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic, PID: 3493
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean
java.sql.ResultSet.next()' on a null object reference
at com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic.DatabaseConnectivity.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:157)
at com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic.DatabaseConnectivity.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:123)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-05 23:00:31.890 3493-3503/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
07-05 23:00:31.890 3493-3503/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.postgresql.core.ProtocolConnection.close()' on a null object reference
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.close(PgConnection.java:690)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.finalize(PgConnection.java:924)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:191)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:174)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-05 23:05:35.610 8049-8049/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex) with checksum 0x373843a4 in OatFile /data/data/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic/cache/slice-slice_1-classes.dex
07-05 23:05:36.150 8049-8062/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1899(738KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 43% free, 967KB/1698KB, paused 8.436ms total 25.104ms
07-05 23:05:36.416 8049-8049/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-05 23:05:36.677 8049-8059/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
07-05 23:05:36.677 8049-8059/com.example.nikhil.soundofmusic E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.postgresql.core.ProtocolConnection.close()' on a null object reference
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.close(PgConnection.java:690)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.finalize(PgConnection.java:924)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:191)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:174)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

thanks in advance for any help